# Linked List Sort is not working

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to make a linked list and sort said Linked list at the same time, but I can't quite figure out how to get the code to completely sort the list.

Here are my classes:

```
class PayRoll{
private:
    string EmployeeName; // employee name
    double PayRate; // employee pay rate
    double HoursWorked; // employee hours worked
public:
    void setRate(double); // set rate
    void setName(string); // set name
    void setHours(double); // set hours worked
    string getName(){return EmployeeName;};
    double getHours(){return HoursWorked;};
    double getRate() {return PayRate;};
    double getPaid(){return (PayRate*HoursWorked);};
```

};

```
class PayRollList{
    private:
        struct ListNode {
            PayRoll p;
            ListNode* next;
        };
        ListNode *head;
    public:
        PayRollList() { head = nullptr; };
        void insert(string, double, double); // name, rate, hours
        void printPayChecks(); // print name and total pay for all employees
};
```

The main problem i believe is the insert function here. The implementation of data is successfully going through, so i neglected to put that here. I can't get this part to work though.

```
void PayRollList::insert(string EmpName, double rate, double hours){
ListNode* newNode = new ListNode;

newNode->p.setName(EmpName);
newNode->p.setRate(rate);
newNode->p.setHours(hours);
newNode->next = nullptr;

ListNode* current = this->head;
ListNode* temp;

if ( head == nullptr ){
    this->head = newNode; }
else {
    current = this->head;
    while ( current->next != nullptr ){
        if ( newNode->p.getRate() < current->p.getRate() && this->head == current){
            temp = current;
            this->head = newNode;
            newNode->next = temp;
            return;
        }
        else if ( newNode->p.getRate() < current->p.getRate() && this->head != current){
            temp = current;
            current = current->next;
            newNode->next = current;
            temp->next = newNode;
            return;
        }
        else if ( newNode->p.getRate() < current->p.getRate() ){
            temp = current;
            current = current->next;
            newNode->next = current;
            temp->next = newNode;
            return;
        }
        else current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newNode;
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The pointer-to-pointer trick is to keep a backwards reference. You could accomplish the same using a single-depth pointer and always referencing the ->next element for comparison, but then you need to special case inserting the first element of the linked list.

```
void PayRollList::insert(string EmpName, double rate, double hours){
    ListNode* newNode = new ListNode;

    newNode->p.setName(EmpName);
    newNode->p.setRate(rate);
    newNode->p.setHours(hours);
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    ListNode** current = &(this->head);
    while (*current != nullptr && (*current)->p.getRate() < newNode->p.getRate()) {
        current = &((*current)->next);
    }
    newNode->next = *current;
    *current = newNode;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Any chance you could explain how double pointers work in this context?

Comment: https://ibb.co/e5ZNZQ

Since current is a a pointer-to-pointer, it points to the "next" pointer *within* each instance of the ListNode class.